# How do I find the DataSnap server in DCOMCNFG?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2009, datasnap

On Windows 7 I tried to register a new DataSnap server using tregsrvr (using run as administrator), which runs and confirms that the registration succeeded.

However I can not find the server in DCOMCNFG to check its settings. There are quite many DCOM entries, which have a GUID as their ID. I know one of them should be the DataSnap server.

However the GUID displayed in the DCOMCNFG list does not equal the server's GUID I can see in Delphi IDE. Is this correct? Is there a quick way to find my DataSnap server in the DCOMCNFG?

Update: strange, today (after a server restart) I found the entry in dcomcnfg. I was also able to register the server on a Windows 2008 R2 box, even without restarting the server GUID (CoClass) was there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 7 at hand to confirm this but I think under "DCOM Config" there should be an entry displayed with the Help string of the CoClass of your appserver as stated in the type library of your project.
By default, it looks like "[coclassname] [version] Object", e.g. "MyServer 1.0 Object".
Also, the GUID shown in the properties is the CLSID of the CoClass.

Comment: Yes, for a new Delphi 2009 app the name is displayed. For a server ported from Delphi 7, there is only a GUID, so I will check where the files are different...

Comment: So maybe the GUID is the CLSID of your CoClass?

Comment: The GUID displayed in the DCOMCNFG list is not equal to the server's GUID which I can see in Delphi IDE. I am in the office later this week and check the difference between D7 and 2009 then.

Answer (score 0):

I think DCOMCNFG has been replaced (I think since Windows 2000!) with the Component Services management module. On 2000 and XP it was available via the Adminstrative Tools section of the Control Panel. I just recently baught a new Windows 7 laptop, and I can't seem to find where the friendly folk at MS hid the Administrative tools, but mmc.exe still works (just type "mmc" and enter in the 'search' box of the start menu), and if you do File > Add/remove Module, Component Services is in the list. There you can do what you could before with DCOMCNFG, and all of the other COM+ management. (Which i learned all about using the 'high isolation' level of IIS 5 and 6, IIS 7 introduced application pools and kind of let go of COM+...)

Comment: I enter dcomconfg in the run... dialog and the management module opens which has the DCOM (and other) entries